# Replacing repeated words within a string with integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, text-processing

I have problem in string maniputation with C++.

The Rule: if the same 'word' is repeated from sentences or paragraph I want it to become an integer.

Example:

- input: `we prefer questions that can be answered, not just we discussed that.`
- output: `1 prefer questions 2 can be answered, not just 1 discussed 2.`

```
1 we
2 that
```

Comment: So, if I may rephrase, you wish to replace all instances of repeated words with a numerical replacement for that word.  Each subsequently-encountered repeated word gets a new, incremented number.  Sounds like a unique compression scheme...

Comment: yupz...
can you help me to solve it? ^^
-sorry for my bad english-

Comment: You will benifit from this if only if you give it a go... write some code!!! If it doesn't work as you want it to, a lot of folks here will be glad to help when you're debugging.

Comment: As other have said, show us what you've done so far.  We will help you from there.

Comment: @ afterlife
Sorry, but until now, i still cannot find the algorhytm. and i'm still newbie with c or c++.

Comment: If you had to do it by hand, what would you do?  What's your mind's algorithm?

Comment: My mind's algorithm is normally to give up and go get a beer :-)

Comment: hmm...
maybe i will get each word, then i will trace every word.
if i find the same word, i will change 'this word' it into numerical
and.. dont know what to do after this..

Comment: @Pax
yes, after this problem have solved. hehe :-)
Anyways thanks for the algorythm

Comment: this is a homework problem and it requires C++? it is not a simple beginner C++ homework #1 or #2... if any language can be used, a scripting language can be used to solve it in about 1 to 2 minutes

Comment: @jian lin
do you have any scripting language that can solve it?
what kind?
can you help me?

Comment: If you've spent the same amount of time on thinking about the solution that you are spending on SO you would already had the solution ...

Comment: hehe...until now I still dont have the solution...

Answer (score 4):

This type of problem is usually much easier to solve if you use an associative array to keep track of the words you have already seen. Try using an [STL map](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/map/start) for storing words you have seen already. It will take some work to get your logic set up correctly, but a map will definitely help with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

This is the approach I would take (algorithms only, since it's homework).

1. Create a data structure mapping words to counts.
2. Process the text one word at a time.

   - if it's a new word, add it to the data structure and set its count to 1.
   - if it's an existing one, just increment the count.
3. Once all words are processed, go through each word in the data structure, giving a unique integer to those with a count greater than one.
4. Create a new text string, empty to start with then process the text word-by-word again.

   - if the word has a count of one, append that word to the new string.
   - if the count is greater than one, append the unique integer.

Comment: This is the one that holds the key for the novice programmer:  the solution involves two consecutive passes over the data.  Consider carefully what you need to do in pass 1, and what you then do in pass 2.

Answer (score 1):

> Parsing:

```
   For each word in the string
          Check whether the word exists in map<WORD,Counter>
          if the WORD is new the insert into the map with counter =0
          otherwise increment the counter associated with word.
```

> Output:(create new sentence)

```
For each word in the string
      Lookup into the vector for counter value
      if counter ==0 then insert WORD as it is
      otherwise convert the counter to string and insert
```